# Pandas: Conditional aggregation mean and median

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, aggregation

**Set up**

I'm scraping housing ads with Scrapy and analyse the results with pandas.

I construct dataframes, grouping over location and aggregating over several housing characteristics (e.g. rent).

---

**Problem**

I want to construct the same dataframes, i.e. grouping over location and aggregating over housing characteristics, but now also aggregating conditionally.

That is, I have a characteristic for each housing ad named `type` which is either `1` or `2`. I want to group over location and aggregate the housing characteristics also conditionally on `type` being `1` or `2`.

---

**Code**

```
group = ['borough','click district name for housing ads','district']
mdf['# for rent'] = 1 
aggregator = {
        'median rent pw':'median',
        'rent pw':'mean',
        '# of roommates':'mean',
        '# for rent':'sum',
        }

badf = mdf.groupby(group)['median rent pw','rent pw','# of roommates'].agg(aggregator)
```

This is my working code, which does not aggregate conditionally.

I was thinking I could split `mdf` in two DataFrames – one for each `type` – and subsequently run the code on the two frames and merge the results into one table. That seems a bit inefficient though.

Preferably, I want the code to do something like this:

```
    aggregator = {
        'median rent pw type 1 ':'median, conditionally on type = 1',
        'median rent pw type 2 ':'median, conditionally on type = 2',
        'median rent pw':'median',
        'rent pw type 1':'mean, conditionally on type = 1',
        'rent pw type 2':'mean, conditionally on type = 2',
        'rent pw':'mean',
        '# of roommates':'mean',
        '# for rent':'sum',
        }
```

How do I go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I think you can just include `type` in the `groupby`

```
group = ['type', 'borough','click district name for housing ads','district']
mdf['# for rent'] = 1 
aggregator = {
        'median rent pw':'median',
        'rent pw':'mean',
        '# of roommates':'mean',
        '# for rent':'sum',
        }

badf = mdf.groupby(group)['median rent pw','rent pw','# of roommates'].agg(aggregator)
```

Then you should be able to get at `type == 1`

```
badf.loc[1]
```

Or

```
badf.xs(1)
```

Comment: I'll be damned. Thanks! Btw, both `badf.loc[1]` and `badf.xs(1)` work, it seems.